# How to convert xml data into an arraylist of userdefined objects

Tags: android, arraylist, xml-parsing

Sample Class :

```
Class Circle
{
    String id;
    double radius;
    Center center;

    Center
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    }
}
```

I would like to store info in an xml file and at run time read from it and populate an array-list of Circle objects. I tried looking at the android inbuilt parser but i dont quiet under stand how it works , also not sure which parser is the best for this operatinn.

Sample XML

```
<Circles>
    <circle1>
        <id></id>
        <radius></radius>
        <center>
            <x></x>
            <y></y>
        </center> 
    </circle1>
    <circle2>
        <id></id>
        <radius></radius>
        <center>
            <x></x>
            <y></y>
        </center>
    </circle2> 
</Circles>
```

As i am currently not able to use a database and since the data is permanent, i thought xml would be a good choice. I am open to other solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of databindung frameworks  to convert your XML into objects ( but please choose one that uses pull-parser).   Notable examples are:  jackson , xstream  ant 2390000 others.  Pick one that most suites you, has lowest memory foorprint and is  pure java with less external dependencies.

And I would suggest to change your XML structure somehow:

```
<Circles>
<circle>
    <id></id>
    <radius></radius>
    <center>
        <x></x>
        <y></y>
    </center> 
</circle>
<circle>
    <id></id>
    <radius></radius>
    <center>
        <x></x>
        <y></y>
    </center>
</circle>
```

Use  as list element instead  of numbering them  - makes databindung easier

Comment: Thanks for the correction on the xml.. The example code on the net don't seem to explain how the parsing works, just the code is provided. Perhaps you know of blog that does some explaining on the concept. I would appreciate it.

Comment: There is a lot of examples.  Look at the XStream 2 minutes tutorial: http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html   other databindung tools work pretty similar